# Custom analysis of pcap capture files

Tags: java

I want to do an analysis on pcap files, but `tshark` seems rather heavy for the simple analysis I want, such as:

- number of packets
- capture duration
- total bytes

Is there an easier way to get these statistics?

Answer (score 1):

Using lovely python in a lazy way:

```
# apt-get install python-pypcap

>>> import pcap
>>> p = pcap.pcap(name="hs22v-boot.pcap")
>>> packets = [x for x in p]
>>> duration = packets[-1][0] - packets[0][0]
>>> totalbytes = sum([len(x[1]) for x in packets])
>>> numpackets = len(packets)
>>> duration, totalbytes, numpackets
(113.37264108657837, 193812281, 227491)
```

Comment: Turning this into properly efficient code is left as an exercise for the reader.